# Have anyone used GoDaddy's Code Signing Certificate with ClickOnce

Tags: clickonce, certificate, code-signing

According to the FAQ to GoDaddy they support SignTool from Microsoft, but mage.exe isn't mentioned. Mage.exe is used to sign the application, but I haven't been able to figure out if mage.exe uses SignTool. If anyone have used GoDaddy's code signing certificate for ClickOnce a short confirmation would have been appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm using GoDaddy's code signing certificate with a ClickOnce deployment. To sign the deployment, I just call the [SignFile Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164304.aspx) in MSBuild during the deployment build script.

Comment: Any reason for not using mage.exe?

Comment: Our deployment script is completely written in MSBuild, so we can use GenerateApplicationManifest and GenerateDeploymentManifest tasks to create the .application files. The outputs of those tasks feed directly into the SignFile task, eliminating the need to use mage.

Comment: @DavGarcia is not possible just to right click on the project -> properties -> Signing? Thanks a lot

Comment: @DavGarcia I know this is forever ago, but I need to figure out how to Authenticode sign with an ECC cert on a YubiKey. Mage won't do it, and I know you can do ECC with signtool, so I'm off to figure that out. If you've done it and have a cheat-sheet, I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Both the Mage.exe as well as the SignFile MSBuild Task use the SignTool.exe to sign the files. (reflectored both tools, to build my own custom solution)